# Android talkback announce "in in" at the ending of heading level 1

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I open a web page in Android, turn on Talkback and focus on a heading level 1 "Create a new team". However, the Talkback read outloud "Create a new team, heading level 1, **in, in.**".

[image]

What does "in, in" mean? How do I get rid of it?
Thanks in advance,

UPDATED:
this behavior only happens on specific device.

Comment: Could you please try and provide an interactive code example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the accessibility properties of that element? Please do so in your developer tools, and share the result in your question. “In” might hint to some grouping roles like `section` and `document`, which are not shared in your screenshot.